# C# Windows Forms - MenuItem Click Event - getting the MenuItem Text

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I get the text of any given menu item that has been clicked on?

The menu is populated dynamically, so it seems I am limited to this:

```
 Menu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("MenuName", new EventHandler(menu_click)));
```

Unfortunately, I cannot see that Eventhandler has the text/name of the menu item that has been clicked.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Ask an easy question, get a LOT of similar answers :)

Comment: Ha....they're only easy if you know the answer!!

Answer (score 6):

What type of menu is this?

Since you seem to be attaching the event directly to the menu item then I would guess that sender is what you are looking for...

```
private void menu_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
    // Access the clicked item here..
    string text = mi.Text; // I guess it's called text(?)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your event handler will have been given the object that raised the event as the "sender" parameter. You'll have to cast it to a MenuItem, then examine its "Text" property:

```
public void MenuClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;

   var menuText = menuItem.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The event handler should have an `object sender` parameter.  If you cast this to a `MenuItem`, you should be able to access the `Header` property.

```
void menu_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedItem = sender as MenuItem;

    if (clickedItem == null)
        return;

    if (clickedItem.HasHeader)
    {
        var text = clickedItem.Header;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the sender object to a menu item and retrieve the *Text* property.

Sample code

```
Menu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("MenuName", (o, ev) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show((o as MenuItem).Text);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

With the standard .NET event handler function signature ...

```
(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) ' VB.NET syntax
```

... in the event handler, you can cast `sender` as `MenuItem` and access all of the properties.