# MenuItems Clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

I have `Right-click` menu items, that have `sub menu items`. What i would like to do is if one of the 3 sub menu items was clicked, it would open the same form but pass in different variables.
Sub Menu Items;
1- Manager
2- Staff
3- Customer

Whichever one is picked it should pass the  Name be it Manager,Staff or Customer to the one form.

Thanks

EDIT 1:
MAIN FORM

```
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();
            MenuItem Message = new MenuItem("Message", Message_Click);
            Message.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Manager", Manager_Click));
            Message.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("-"));
            Message.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Staff", Staff_Click));
            Message.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Customer", Customer_Click));


        }


 private void Manager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      FrmMessage frmMessage = new FrmMesage();

        frmMessage.ShowDialog();
       frmMessage.Dispose();
    }

    private void Staff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmMessage frmMessage = new FrmMesage();

        frmMessage.ShowDialog();
       frmMessage.Dispose();
    }

    private void Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       FrmMessage frmMessage = new FrmMesage();

        frmMessage.ShowDialog();
       frmMessage.Dispose();
    }
```

MESSAGE FORM;

```
 private void PopulateFields()
    {

        txtMessage.Text = Company.ManagerName.ToString();
        OR
        txtMessage.Text = Company.StaffName.ToString();
        OR 
        txtMessage.Text = Company.CustomerName.ToString();


    }
```

EDIT 2:

I have  2 `forms`, The first form has a `datagrid`, on this datagrid there are the above `MenuItems`. On the second `form` their are 3 `TextBoxes`- `To`, `From`, `Message`whichever `MenuItem`- `Manager`, `Staff`, `Customer` is picked it will populate the `To` `TextBox` with the name of the Manager or Staff or Customer, but it does not do this. Does this my question clearer?

Thanks

Comment: OK so what's the actual problem?

Comment: Not sure on how to get register which sub Menu item was clicked on the new form.

Comment: Use the sender object of the click method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Winforms - MenuItem Click Event - getting the MenuItem Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488397/c-sharp-winforms-menuitem-click-event-getting-the-menuitem-text)

Comment: It would be awesome to have a [mcve]. In other words, code which we can run at our end that we could use to show you how it's done.

Comment: @Enigmativity, i have added code .

Comment: Which bit is not working? The example @Sinatr linked to shows you exactly how to get which menu item was clicked. All you need to do now is pass that to your form through the constructor or in a property.

Comment: You still haven't stated an actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices.

You could inherit `FrmMesage` down to three specific sub classes that specialize for each type.

```
public class FrmMesageManager : FrmMesage { /* with appropriate overrides */ }

public class FrmMesageCustomer : FrmMesage { /* with appropriate overrides */ }

public class FrmMesageStaff : FrmMesage { /* with appropriate overrides */ }
```

Then you'd do:

```
private void Manager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmMessageManager frmMessage = new FrmMessageManager();

    frmMessage.ShowDialog();
    frmMessage.Dispose();
}
```

...etc.

Or you could add a constructor to `FrmMesage`

```
public partial class FrmMesage
{
    private string _user;
    public FrmMesage(string user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }
}
```

Then you'd do:

```
private void Manager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmMessage frmMessage = new FrmMessage("Manager");

    frmMessage.ShowDialog();
    frmMessage.Dispose();
}
```

Or you could add a public property to `FrmMesage`

```
public partial class FrmMesage
{
    private string User { get; set; }
}
```

Then you'd do:

```
private void Manager_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrmMessage frmMessage = new FrmMessage();

    frmMessage.User = "Manager";

    frmMessage.ShowDialog();
    frmMessage.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: For a complete solution don't forget to include an example of getting the menu text to pass to the form. I know there's a link in the comments but it'd be handy if it's shown here.